# How to use cookies outside controller?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I've setup cookies inside a Login Controller. Whenever I'm trying to get the values of cookies outside of controller it's throwing an error. please check this out what I'm missing.

**Controller** After i get success response I'm setting cookies

```
app.controller('AngularLoginController', ['$scope','$http','$cookies','$rootScope', function($scope, $http, 
$cookies,$rootScope) {   
    $scope.loginForm = function() {         
            $http.post("login.php", {
            'email' :$scope.inputData.email,
            'password':$scope.inputData.password
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);                  
                if ( data != 'wrong') {                     
                var loggedIn = $cookies.get('loggedIn');
                // Putting cookies
                $cookies['myCookieArray']= {'loggedIn':true,'username':data};
                getmycookiesback = $cookies['myCookieArray'];
                window.location.href = '#/userlist';
                $rootScope.display = true;                  
                $rootScope.username = getmycookiesback.username;                    
                } 
               else {
                $scope.errorMsg = "Invalid Email and Password";
                                }
        })
        }           
}]);
```

After I login it calls AngularLoginController  and set Cookies values after success Response.

**Outside Controller**  if I'm comparing value of cookies it's throwing error getmycookiesback is not defined

```
var onlyLoggedIn = function ($location,$q,$cookies,$rootScope) { 
var deferred = $q.defer();
var url = $location.absUrl();
if (getmycookiesback.loggedIn === "undefined") { // Error on This line 
    deferred.reject();      
    window.location.href = '#/login';       
}
else{ 
    deferred.resolve(); 
    $rootScope.display = true;
    $rootScope.username = getmycookiesback.username;
    window.location.href = url;
    alert(getmycookiesback.username);
    //$cookies.remove('loggedIn');

    return true;
}
return deferred.promise;
};
```

Why it's undefined if i have defined it in Controller. 
Is there another way i can get value of cookies outside controller ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is undefined; it appears to be a local variable in that function scope.

You may want to take a look at Angular Services for things you want to access globally - you may want to implement a function on a service to do this, or store that information locally within the service and provide a function to access it - take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).